# Loading dictionary object causing memory spike

Tags: python, django

I have a dictionary object with about 60,000 keys that I cache and access in my Django view. The view provides basic search functionality where I look for a search term in the dictionary like so:

```
projects_map = cache.get('projects_map')
projects_map.get('search term')
```

However, just grabbing the cached object (in line 1) causes a a giant spike in memory usage on the server - upwards of 100MBs sometimes - and the memory isn't released even after the values are returned and the template rendered.

How can I keep the memory from jacking up like this? Also, I've tried explicitly deleting the object after I grab the value but even that doesn't release the memory spike.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

### Update: Solution I ultimately implemented

I decided to implement my own indexing table in which I store the keys and their pickled value. Now, instead of using `get()` on a dictionary, I use:

`ProjectsIndex.objects.get(index_key=<search term>)`

and unpickle the value. This seems to take care of the memory issue as I'm no longer loading a giant object into memory. It adds another small query to the page but that's about it. Seems to be the perfect solution...for now.

Comment: Wonder if running gc.collect helps freeing memory

Comment: @YevgenYampolskiy Just tried gc.collect - didn't help.

Comment: Did you try it after projects_map got out of scope? Just checking

Comment: I did. It didn't do anything.

Comment: What actually `cache` object is? Is it just plain `dict` with all 60k cached objects inside? Or is it some sort of smart cache which loads missing items on access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

..what about using some appropriate service for caching, such as [redis](http://redis.io/) or [memcached](http://memcached.org/) instead of loading the huge object in memory python-side? This way, you'll even have the ability to scale on extra machines, should the dictionary grow more..

Anyways, the 100MB memory contain all the data + hash index + misc. overhead; I noticed myself the other day that many times memory doesn't get deallocated until you quit the Python process (I filled up couple gigs of memory from the Python interpreter, loading a huge json object.. :)); it would be interesting if anybody has a solution for that..

### Update: caching with very few memory

Your options with only 512MB ram are:

- Use redis, and have a look here http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization (but I suspect 512MB isn't enough, even optimizing)
- Use a separate machine (or a cluster of, since both memcached and redis support sharding) with way more ram to keep the cache
- Use the [database cache backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#database-caching), much slower but less memory-consuming, as it saves everything on the disk
- Use [filesystem cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#filesystem-caching) (although I don't see the point of preferring this over database cache)

and, in the latter two cases, try splitting up your objects, so that you never retrieve megabytes of objects from the cache at once.

### Update: lazy dict spanning over multiple cache keys

You can replace your cached dict with something like this; this way, you can continue treating it as you would with a normal dictionary, but data will be loaded from cache only when you really need it.

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from UserDict import DictMixin

class LazyCachedDict(DictMixin):
    def __init__(self, key_prefix):
        self.key_prefix = key_prefix

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return cache.get('%s:%s' % (self.key_prefix, name))

    def __setitem__(self, name, value):
        return cache.set('%s:%s' % (self.key_prefix, name), value)

    def __delitem__(self, name):
        return cache.delete('%s:%s' % (self.key_prefix, name))

    def has_key(self, name):
        return cache.has_key(name)

    def keys():
        ## Just fill the gap, as the cache object doesn't provide
        ## a method to list cache keys..
        return []
```

And then replace this:

```
projects_map = cache.get('projects_map')
projects_map.get('search term')
```

with:

```
projects_map = LazyCachedDict('projects_map')
projects_map.get('search term')
```

Comment: I am using Django's FileBasedCache at the moment. I suppose I could give Memcached a try.

Comment: I gave Memcached a try. Unfortunately, my hosting has a memory limit of 512MB and that's apparently a bit too much to cache for Memcached.

Comment: Ok, you should definitely try redis then.. and, try splitting that dictionary up a bit. ie, instead of caching the whole thing in ``projects_map``, use different "namespaced" keys, such as ``projects_map.<key1>``, ``projects_map.<key2>``, etc. this way, you load in memory only the interesting part, and not the whole, huge, object.

Comment: ..nope, I wasn't taking into account that you are running everything on a single machine.. then, a part from having a look at http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization, your best option is using django database cache https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#database-caching or filesystem cache https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#filesystem-caching that are much slower, but store everything to disk, instead of keeping everything in memory.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm already using FileBasedCache. And the memory spike is occurring when fetching the object from cache. So while Memcached has its own memory requirements, fetching the object from FileBasedCache or DB cache will still require a good chunk of memory apparently to load the object.

Comment: ok. so, try splitting your object over different keys, and load in memory only the parts you need. You could even use a lazy dictionary-like object to do that in an almost-seamingless way..

Comment: With your latest update with UserDict, you entered a realm of Python I'm not entirely familiar with :-) That said, I'm not entirely sure what's happening with your class that's so different from just pulling up a key from cache. I think you're assuming I don't always need to read the object, but I do. Every search needs to look into the object to see if a match is available.

Comment: That object just "emulates" a Python dict: when you try accessing an item, with `['']` or `.get()`, it will request the needed object from the cache and return it; similarly, when you set a key to a value, it will set it in the cache. The only difference is that instead of loading in memory the whole object at once, it just loads the parts you actually need.

Comment: By the way, if you are using the dict to perform lookups, ie. you are iterating over the keys to look for something or so, perhaps you should use a standard database model instead..

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I decided to try Django's DB cache but it kept crapping out with DB errors. I went ahead and created my own index table and decided to store keys and pickled values. That seems to be working great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Windows works, but in Linux a process practically cannot return memory to system. It's because a process address space is contiguous and the only available system call to increase memory is `brk()`, which just increases a pointer which marks last address available to a process.

All allocators which applications use (`malloc` etc.) are defined in user-space as a library. They operate on a byte-blocks level and use `brk()` to increase internal memory-pool only. In a running application this memory pool is cluttered with requested blocks. The only possibility to return memory to the system is when the last part of a pool has no blocks used (very unlikely that this will be of significant size, because even simple applications allocate and deallocate thousands of objects).

So a bloat caused by a memory spike will stay till the end. Solutions:

- avoid the spike by optimizing memory usage, even if caused by temporary objects (eg: process a file line by line instead of reading whole contents at once)
- put the cache in another process (memcached, as suggested in the first answer)
- use a serialized dictionary (`gdbm`) or some other storage detached from process' private memory (`mmap`, shared memory)

Comment: Understanding `brk` is interesting, but this answer is incomplete and misleading, and probably irrelevant to the question. While `brk` works as described, it is not how `malloc` implementations allocate large objects (one classic choice is to `mmap` from `/dev/zero`), and high-level languages like Python have their own memory allocators anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If `get` on particular key is the only operation you perform, why not to keep all keys separately in cache? That way all entries will end up in separate files and django will be able to access them [quickly](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/cache/backends/filebased.py#L131).

The update will be much more painfull of course, but you can abstract it nicely. First thing I can think of is some cache key prefix.

The code could look like `cache.get('{prefix}search_term')` then.

**Edit:**

We're trying to solve wrong problem here. You don't need caching. The data gets updated, not dumped (after 5 mins or so).

You need to create a database table with all your entries.

If you don't have access to any database server from your setting, try to use sqlite. It's file based and should serve your purpose well.

Comment: I tried caching individual keys. The process (before I killed it) took an hour. I don't think this is viable given that I'll be updating this object once every 24 hours.

Comment: If you update data it shouldn't go to cache but to db at the first place. See update above.